# What does @link mean in java/Android documentation?

Tags: android, javadoc

What does this mean:

```
{@link KeyEvent#KEYCODE_ENTER}
```

I have seen it a couple times and I'm not quite sure what it represents. I am writing a testing program using Robotium, JUnit, and Android. If anyone could offer some clarification on the subject, more specificly, the {@link} part, that would be great!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's an annotation used so when you generate the Javadoc, you'll have a link for the specified item. In this case, the KeyEvent class, with the anchor of KEYCODE_ENTER.

Answer (score 5):

I have not formally learned so perhaps someone can expand upon what I say.

It is shorthand that tells the java docs to insert a link to the desired place when they are being viewed. For instance when you view the javadocs for whatever method has that inside your IDE you'll be shown a link that will take you to the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER javadoc upon being clicked.

Answer (score 3):

With `@link` you can link to the Javadoc of a different class or class-member. See also the [Javadoc documentation for `@link`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@link%7D)

When the Javadoc is generated, a link to the right page + anchor is inserted. This allows for cross-referencing other parts of the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link to another class. You should be able to click this link in IDE e.g. Intellij IDEA and Eclipse. Very helpful to link other classes in comments